# Implementing stack in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack

I am working on implementing stack in C++ without STL libraries.

Here is my code for the Header file

```
// File: stack.h: header file
#ifndef STACK_H           
#define STACK_H   

class Stack {
    int MaxStack;
    int EmptyStack;
    int top;
    int* items;
    public:
    Stack(int);                  // Constructor
    ~Stack();                   //Destructor

    //Member Functions
    void push(int);
    char pop();
    int empty();
    int full();
};
#endif // STACK_H
```

And the Cpp file

```
// File: stack.cpp: stack functions


#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;



// Constructor with argument
Stack::Stack(int size) {
    MaxStack = size;
    EmptyStack = -1;
    top = EmptyStack;
    items = new int[MaxStack];
}
// Destructor
Stack::~Stack() { delete[] items; }

void Stack::push(int c) {
    items[++top] = c;
}

char Stack::pop() {
    return items[top--];
}

// Test for Full stack
int Stack::full()  {
    return top + 1 == MaxStack;
}

// Test for Empty stack
int Stack::empty()  {
    return top == EmptyStack;
}
```

Before making a main to test the class when I run this I get these two errors

!(http://postimg.org/image/pnjzd9axt/)

Any help on how to solve these two errors ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: the image is not available?

Comment: Please don't post images of errors, copy-paste it *verbatim* in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that you don't have a main function.

The errors like: 
`Unresolved external symbol` are the compiler way of saying: I want X function, I expect it to be declared but I can not find it in the compiled and linked modules

Answer (score 1):

The main function is not defined.

Add the following to your source code: `int main() { return 0; }`

As indicated by Emil, the compiler cannot find the definition for the main function.

Comment: add the following to your source code...
As indicated by emil, the compiler cannot find the definition for the main function.

int main()
{
  return 0;
}